# Should I run multiple SELECTs inside a PDO transaction for performance gains?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo

Are PDO transcations intended just for UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE or can you achieve performance gains if you use a transaction for mulitple SELECT queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a purist point of view, it **would be wrong** to use a transaction on SELECT statements 'to improve performance'. Use a transaction to be sure to not get inconsistencies in the data.

From a performance point of view, locking the tables so no other statement can access it in order to speed up your SELECTs **might work** - but there are probably **better solutions** than that. For example, use the **`HIGH_PRIORITY`** attribute in your [SELECT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> HIGH_PRIORITY gives the SELECT higher
>   priority than a statement that updates
>   a table. You should use this only for
>   queries that are very fast and must be
>   done at once. A SELECT HIGH_PRIORITY
>   query that is issued while the table
>   is locked for reading runs even if
>   there is an update statement waiting
>   for the table to be free. This affects
>   only storage engines that use only
>   table-level locking (such as MyISAM,
>   MEMORY, and MERGE).

This way you use the appropriate method to reach the goal, instead of some hack about which other developers (or even a future you) will wonder why it exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't modifying data, there's not much point in using a transaction, regardless of the impact on performance (which it would actually hurt, not help, since it takes time/resources to manage a transaction).

Of course, there are a few exceptions like if you are trying to set timeouts or lock modes, but in general, explicit transactions are a waste for read-only operations.

Answer (score 1):

You will not gain performance by using transaction.

To gain performance, you can do an `EXPLAIN` and use that to tune your queries.